# Twitter Bootstrap dropdowns appearing under YouTube embed code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap downdown code to build my navigation however, I have a Youtube video just below the navigation bar and when the user hovers over the nav item the dropdown appears underneath the YouTube iFrame. I have had a little play with the Z-Index on both elements but this doesn't seem to make a difference. Any help appreciated and an the example can be found here: http://bit.ly/YKXJEq

EDIT: This only seems to be an issue with certain versions on IE. Testing on IE9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `wmode=transparent` with the video url

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/vmPm5aaU0dg?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent
```

```
<iframe style="z-index:-9999;" width="292" height="306" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vmPm5aaU0dg?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Great! it works! I will accept the answer in 3 minutes when it will let me :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TheRabbitFactory u r welcme :)